# Use same struct across multiple test files

Tags: testing, rust, rust-crates

I have two test files located in the `tests` directory. Each test file contains a test function and a common struct. For example, they both contain:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct MyStructure {
    a_value: u8,
}

#[test]
// ...some test functions...
```

The struct `MyStructure` is exactly the same between the two test files. As my struct uses a macro from the `serde_derive` crate, the line `#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive` is required.

In order to avoid code repetition, I would like to declare my struct only once. From what I understand, every file from the `tests` directory is compiled as an individual crate, so it seems impossible to edit the test file and put the struct definition into a separate file in the `tests` directory:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;

mod structure;

#[test]
// ...some test function...
```

```
#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Structure {
    a_value: u8,
}
```

This first try leads to `error[E0468]: an extern crate loading macros must be at the crate root`. This is normal as `structure` is now a sub-module.

Removing `#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;` from `structure` doesn't help either, as `structure` is compiled as an individual crate, and now `Deserialize` cannot be found: `error: cannot find derive macro Deserialize in this scope`.

What is the proper way to move `MyStructure` (including the macro usage) into a separate common file and define it only once for all my test files?